# Android 1.6 to 2.2

Tags: android

I'm developing a simple app for Android-2.2. What are some key features that can make the app not work for 1.6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a big topic.  The move from 1.6 to 2.0 saw some pretty big changes and then there were some significant changes from 2.1 to 2.2.  I would check out the [Android 2.2 platform highlights](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.2-highlights.html) to get an idea of what's new in 2.2 for starters.  If you're building a "simple" app, I would imagine it will still work without much trouble.  AFAIK, the biggest changes to the platform from a developer standpoint is the [media framework](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.2-highlights.html#PlatformTechnologies) additions.  I would also check out the [Android 2.0 platform highlights](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.0-highlights.html) as well to get an idea of what changed from 1.6 to 2.0.